# how to re-order commits in Git non-interactively

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

What non-interactive git command(s) achieve the change from Before to After?

Before:

```
A---B---C---D
```

After:

```
A---C'---B'---D'
```

Answer (score 30):

In your case, you can rebase interactive: `git rebase -i HEAD~4` Then you can just reorder your picks

For example lets add three more files to our branch:

```
git add A
git commit -m "A"

git add B
git commit -m "B"

git add C
git commit -m "C"
```

Your shortlog will be:

```
$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      B
      C
```

If you want to reorder B with C:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
pick 1f9133d B
pick 33f41be C
```

You just re-order them to be:

```
pick 33f41be C
pick 1f9133d B
```

After you're done writing, see the shortlog:

```
$ git shortlog
 (3):
      A
      C
      B
```

You can do the same thing with all the commits by re-ordering. It is like what you see is what you get, which is pretty cool :)

Comment: How come this answer gets up votes when it clearly does not answer the question? OP asks for a way of doing this NON-INTERACTIVELY and this answer is all about how to do it INTERACTIVELY.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand probably because that's what most people (including me) were looking for, when they came here, though you're absolutely right.

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand People searched for "How to reorder commits in git" and this on helped them :v.

Comment: Let's imagine there is a thousand commits (or a million, if you don't think a thousand lines isn't much in your code editor) between `B` and `C`. How do you do this in a manageable way with an interactive rebase?

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

```
git reset --hard A
git cherry-pick C
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick D
```

There may be a way with `git rebase`, but I didn't really understand it.

Comment: git rebase -i will certainly let you do it; but wasn't sure how you'd achieve the same thing non-interactively

Comment: All `git rebase` does is use `git format-patch` and then `git am` to reapply them (possibly in a different order).  It's a fundamentally interactive process, though, since re-applying the patches out of order can fail and require user intervention.

Comment: I think this really answers the question without rebase -i, except you ordered the cherry-picks B, C, D instead of C, B, D so it doesn't actually solve the problem :)

Comment: @ThomsonComer oops, seems nobody noted this for almost 4 years. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is to the point. Besides, for interactive, it works perfectly for TortoiseGit: tortoisegit show log, reset to "A" (HARD), tortoisegit show *reflog*, right click on the entry *before* the reset, "Show Log...", and then start the cherry picking to reorder your commits. If necessary, start by stashing your uncommitted local changes.

Answer (score 6):

See [How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interative-manner) for using git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner.

Then, if you have formal criteria for reordering commits, you can script that, see for example [Really flatten a git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270357/really-flatten-a-git-merge) to reorder commits by the original commit date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder commits in a script and don't want to deal with the commit hashes, then this seems to work as a general solution (based on Paŭlo Ebermann 's answer):

```
git reset --hard @~3
git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD~1
git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD~2
git cherry-pick ORIG_HEAD
```

I assume that running this sequence of commands twice in a row will restore the commit tree to what it was before, except for changing the changed commit hashes.