# How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?

Tags: git, scripting, git-rebase, non-interactive

Is it possible to do following?

1. Make `git rebase --interactive` to just output standard boilerplate to a file, instead to outputting to a file and opening it in editor.
2. Let the user edit the file.
3. Let user re-run `git rebase` with the name of edited file.
4. Go on with the usual rebase process.

Usecase: scripted rebasing of course. See [how to re-order commits in Git non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981061/how-to-re-order-commits-in-git-non-interactively) for example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270357/really-flatten-a-git-merge for where this would be useful, too.

Comment: Besides git rebase below, git filter-branch is another option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636750/git-filter-branch-msg-filter-to-reword-a-pushed-commit-message

Answer (score 73, accepted):

After some thinking and research, the answer turned out to be trivial: `git rebase -i` takes the editor name from the well-known EDITOR/VISUAL environment variables, so overriding that to point to a non-interactive script does the job.

However, EDITOR/VISUAL applies indifferently to the list of commits, commit messages when rewording and anything else. So, since http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=commit;h=821881d88d3012a64a52ece9a8c2571ca00c35cd , there's a special environment variable GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR which applies only to the commit list.

So, the recipe to re-order or flatten commits is:

Run: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<script> git rebase -i <params>`.
Your `<script>` should accept a single argument: the path to the file containing the standard rebase commit list. It should rewrite it in-place and exit. Usual rebase processing happens after that.

Comment: did not know of `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, seems useful ;)

Comment: Or, instead of creating a script for this sole purpose, just use the existing command `true`, which ignores any arguments and has a fixed return code of `0`.

Comment: @me_and this only helps if you want to do a `rebase -i` without actually reordering the commits.

Comment: Here is another example that fixes a typo in the last five commit messages: `EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/borken/broken/g'" GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/pick/reword/g'" git rebase -i HEAD~5`

Comment: For some unknown reason EDITOR is now ignored by git --version 2.5.5. On the other hand VISUAL still works. So here's another example re-generating the 5 last Change-Id. This assumes the Gerrit commit hook is installed. `VISUAL="sed -i -e '/^[[:blank:]]*Change-Id/ d'" GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/pick/reword/g'" git rebase -i HEAD~5 `. Tested successfully with git version 2.5.5

Comment: Also: make sure `git config --global core.editor` returns empty.

Comment: I found `VISUAL` also didnt work in my attempt at [automated git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949067/git-squash-by-author-all-author-commits-into-a-single-commit/46403701#46403701) , but `GIT_EDITOR` worked.

Comment: @MarcH: Please mention alternatives in comments to somebody else's answer (yet better in your own answer), not by editing content which has somebody else's signature. Thanks.

Comment: Both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` worked for me. `git-2.26.0`.

Answer (score 22):

Adding on to @pfalcon's answer, you can use sed as your GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR.  For example, I wanted to edit each commit, so I did this:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick /e /'" git rebase -i
```

Comment: `-e` is optional in this case. Actually you can even reduce it to `sed -ri 's/pick/e/'`.

Answer (score 10):

The variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` was initially used to change the editor. It is possible to pass a script to this variable to use `git rebase -i` in a non-interactive manner. So it is possible to use:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick 134567/e 1234567/'" git rebase -i 1234567^
```

This command will run `sed` on file provided by `git rebase -i`. It will change the line `pick 134567` into `e 1234567` (and so, edit the commit 1234567). You can change `e` with `r` (rework), `f` (fixup), `s` (squash) or `d` (drop) (the latter is not supported by old versions of `git`).

Based on that, I wrote a script that automatizes this task:

```
#!/bin/bash

ACTION=$1
COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short $2)
[[ "$COMMIT" ]] || exit 1
CORRECT=
for A in p pick r reword e edit s squash f fixup d drop t split; do
     [[ $ACTION == $A ]] && CORRECT=1
done 
[[ "$CORRECT" ]] || exit 1
git merge-base --is-ancestor $COMMIT HEAD || exit 1
if [[ $ACTION == "drop" || $ACTION == "d" ]]; then
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e '/^pick $COMMIT/d'" git rebase -i $COMMIT^^
elif [[ $ACTION == "split" || $ACTION == "t" ]]; then
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/^pick $COMMIT/edit $COMMIT/'" git rebase -i $COMMIT^^ || exit 1
    git reset --soft HEAD^
    echo "Hints:"
    echo "  Select files to be commited using 'git reset', 'git add' or 'git add -p'"
    echo "  Commit using 'git commit -c $COMMIT'"
    echo "  Finish with 'git rebase --continue'"
else
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e 's/^pick $COMMIT/$1 $COMMIT/'" git rebase -i $COMMIT^^
fi
```

The first argument should be one action. The script uses the same action names than git-rebase. It also add 'split' action (and allow to use `drop` with old versions of git).

It also checks that commit you ask for is an ancestor of HEAD. It a common (and really annoying) mistake with `rebase -i`.

The second argument is the commit to want to edit/delete/split/reword.

Then you add an alias to your .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
  autorebase = ! path_to_your_script
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! Could you add comments to explain a little bit what each step does?

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on pfalcon's answer:

> Run `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<script> git rebase -i <params>`. `<script>` should accept single argument - path to file containing standard rebase commit list. The script should rewrite it in-place and exit. Usual rebase processing happens after that.

If you have an environment variable that contains the contents you want:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='echo "$REBASE_DATA" >' git rebase -i [<additional params>]
```

Catting a file would work too:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='cat rebase_data_file >' git rebase -i [<additional params>]
```

Answer (score 7):

To do exactly what the original question asks, use `sed -i '1s/^/b\n/'` as your editor

```sh
git -c sequence.editor="sed -i '1s/^/b\n/'" rebase --interactive
```

#### Explanation

- `git -c` specifies to run the following git command with a specified setting
- `sequence.editor` the setting that determines the "editor" which will edit the redbase-todo file
- `sed -i` run sed command in place

  - `1s` on the first line
  - `^` match the beginning
  - `b\n` insert `b` and a newline `\n` character. `b` or `break` is the rebase command to halt the interactive rebase.
- `rebase --interactive` run rebase command

This stops the interactive rebase immediately.
Now you can edit the `.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` and run `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `touch` as the editor which will touch the file so it will appear modified.  For example

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=touch git rebase -i [commit]
```

To alias it, given `baseline` as a tag I want to rebase against

```
git config alias.baseline '!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=touch git rebase -i baseline'
```

The alias works under Windows because the shell it is executing is `bash` not `cmd`.

Comment: This works well with `git --interactive --exec <cmd> <branch>`.  I set `<cmd>` to a command which runs the tests introduced or modified by my branch, and `<branch>` to `master`.  That causes git to run my tests against each commit in the branch.

Comment: You can use git's native `alias`es by using `-c sequence.editor=touch` instead of `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`. For example, in your `.gitconfig` `[alias]` section: `rs = -c sequence.editor=touch rebase --interactive --autosquash --autostash`.

Answer (score 3):

interactive modes brings up the set editor to work with.
the editor in use can be retrieved with:

```
git config --get core.editor
```

So, if you set a *non-interactive* editor - that is an editor that accepts commands on stdin, you can work with `--interactive` in a *non-interactive* way :)
I know for sure `vim` accepts commands, and so does *the standard editor* `ed`, ofcourse.

so, hold the interactive editor (if wanted)

```
$ ied="$(git config --get core.editor)"
```

set the non-interactive editor

```
$ git config --unset-all core.editor
$ git config --add core.editor ed
```

and do work with it..

```
$ printf '%s\n' "some-ed-cmd" "another-ed-cmd" "wq" | git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

and restore the editor (if wanted)

```
$ git config --unset-all core.editor
$ git config --add core.editor "$ied"
```

Comment: Thanks, we probably started to write answers at similar time, I didn't see yours before I posted mine ;-)

Comment: I think it's simpler to re-define EDITOR, either on a per-session or per-command basis.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against doing `git config --unset-all` or whatever can modify the user's config file in a script. To set a git config variable for one command, use `git -c var=val`, and in this case setting `EDITOR` is much simpler. It's an environment variable, so applies only to the current process, it won't disturb other processes or write anything to disk.

Comment: I found setting `EDITOR` doesnt work any more, and I needed to use `GIT_EDITOR` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. You can use:

```sh
$ GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=true git rebase -i --autosquash $COMMIT_HASH~1
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to provide a custom `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` value that will modify the interactive rebase file. If you just want to perform an action on a single commit, you can do it as follows:

```
# Runs "edit" on HEAD~3
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -ze 's/^pick/edit/'" git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Alternatively, here's a function to generalize this:

```
# Usage: git-rebase-custom edit HEAD~3
git-rebase-custom() {
    local action=$1
    shift

    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -ze 's/^pick/$action/'" git rebase -i "$@"
}
```

Comment: Should quote $1 and $@

Comment: Quoting doesn't matter in variable assignment, but I did remove the assigning to `variables` because it would only pick up the first extra argument unless array assignment was used.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all answers, I made a small script :

```
reword() {
    COMMITHASH=$1
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -re 's/^pick $COMMITHASH/r $COMMITHASH/'" git rebase -i $COMMITHASH~
}
```

For example, if you want to reword the commit `3d4e4bdc`, you can just run the following command in your terminal :

```
reword 3d4e4bdc
```

You can add it to your file `my_aliases.zsh` or `.bashrc`

NOTE : This example is for a reword. If you want to edit the commit, you can replace `$COMMITHASH/r` by `$COMMITHASH/e`

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Jezz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19267103/6261350),
I made a shell-agnostic script ([GitReb](https://github.com/trosh/gitreb))
which works with multiple-argument revisions,
`:/<text>` syntax, root commit and also does some sanity checks.

I also made it simpler and removed the `t`/`split` action
and `delete`->`drop` conversion
which IMO are out of this script's scope.