# Git fix last commit: rebase it with previous one

Tags: git, bash, version-control, alias, rebase

I don't know exactly how to describe it in Git terms but what I do is:

- I make some changes, commit it to a "Add a search box" commit
- I realized I had a parenthesis missing in my code, change it, commit it as "fix"
- Then `git rebase -i HEAD~2`:

  ```
  pick 34ea25a Add a search box
  f 9c4b283 fix
  ```
- Save the file
- And yeah, I have a nice history

But I would like to automate that, so how can I use git rebase without having to open an editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you know that you are going to squash your next commit when doing it, you can just use `git commit --amend` instead. Here's example workflow:

```
$ git commit -am "Add a search box"
$ vim file1.c    # fix something
$ git commit --amend file1.c
```

Git interactive mode, as the name suggest, is designed for interactive use. You can, however, do this using `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` environment variable or `sequence.editor` config option. Both works the same - you can set them to some script that will get a standard interactive rebase file as an input. It's output will be used for actual rebase. You can see some suggestion on how to use it [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner).

Comment: I edited the question to explain that it's not a typo in the commit message but in the code source

Comment: @Dorian: It doesn't matter. Commit ammending is not only about changing commit message. You can also change the commit itself. I've updated my answer to show my point.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. And the rebase scripting will be useful for something else. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution is a simple one and works only if you have a clean branch, i.e. no untracked files, and only for the latest commit.

Add a shell script to a folder in your `PATH` like `~/bin` and name it `git-reword` -- make it executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Message missing"
  exit 0
fi
git reset --soft HEAD^1
git commit -am "$1"
```

In your repo you can now type

```
$ git reword "new message"
```

Comment: But I don't want to reword it, I want to keep the same message as before

Comment: Ok, I see. You mentioned you have a typo. My guess was it being a typo in your commit message.

Comment: When you have a typo in your code, just fix it and do a `git commit --amend`

Comment: Why would someone want to use this script instead of just using `git commit --amend` ?

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski: nobody would - read my comments, check the edits in the main post and think again.