# How do I squash two non-consecutive commits in git, using one line?

Tags: git, bash

I know I can do this using `rebase -i`, but I'm really looking for a way to do it in one line, e.g., with a script.
I took a look at [How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner) for example, but my bashfu is too weak to use it properly.

To be clear, this is what I have right now:

```
A1B2C3 Some commit
AAAAAA Some other commit
A3B2C1 More commit
BBBBBB Another commit
```

I want to squash AAAAAA and BBBBBB in one (or several) git lines, non-interactively.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to write, in any language/etc., a script/program that will transform the `git rebase -i` list of commits into the order you want and set the commit(s) in question to squash?

Comment: I'm okay with python and the likes. I'm just not sure how to apply the script. Should the script receive the rebase -i file (now edited in vim) as input? Or as a raw string?

Comment: Also, all of the examples in the link I've posted have use inline bash code, which I'm less comfortable with, so I'm not sure how to pass a python script  to be applied to begin with...

Comment: @Gal, from that linked answer: "Run `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<script> git rebase -i <params>`. `<script>` should accept single argument - path to file containing standard rebase commit list. The script should rewrite it in-place and exit. Usual rebase processing happens after that." What part of that is confusing you?

Comment: Indeed, that quote from the linked answer is the one I would focus on. If you can write the script then it just needs to operate on the file it is given.

Comment: If you use `git commit --fixup` when you create the commit then you can avoid the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a bash script with the help of the linked question.
I'm attaching it for completeness's sake.
Note: My bash is **ugly**.
One thing of importance though: Since the script cannot accept arguments, I've opted for a self-modifying code.
If there's a better solution (without using globals/environment variables), I'd love to know.
Also, I'm not entirely sure how to swap two lines in bash (and google wasn't a great help), so I ended up using a `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
commit1=???
commit2=???
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then #2 arguments, first phase of script
    #modify lines 2 and 3 with arguments
    currentFile=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}
    cat $currentFile | sed "2s/.*/commit1=$1/" | sed "3s/.*/commit2=$2/" >| $currentFile
    echo "$currentFile"
    exit
fi

# second phase of script
line1=$(grep -nr "pick $commit1" $1 | cut -f1 -d:)
if [ -z $line1 ]; then
    echo "Could not find a match for $commit1"
    exit
fi
line2=$(grep -nr "pick $commit2" $1 | cut -f1 -d:)
if [ -z $line2 ]; then
    echo "Could not find a match for $commit2"
    exit
fi
oldLine=$(($line1<$line2?$line1:$line2))
newLine=$(($line1>$line2?$line1:$line2))
cat $1
#move newLine to be below oldLine, by iterating over all lines in reverse and swapping one by one
for currentLineIndex in `seq $newLine -1 $(expr $oldLine + 2)`; do
    currentLine=$(sed -n "${currentLineIndex}p" "$1")
    nextLineIndex=$(expr $currentLineIndex - 1)
    nextLine=$(sed -n "${nextLineIndex}p" "$1")
    cat $1 | sed $currentLineIndex"s/.*/$nextLine/" | sed $nextLineIndex"s/.*/$currentLine/" >| $1
done

#change the pick to squash
cat $1 | sed $(expr $oldLine + 1)"s/pick/squash/" >| $1
```

example use: `$ GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=$(./rebase.sh d199 a548) git rebase -i 95e2a7c`

Comment: For what's it's worth, running `cat $1 | ...anything... >| $1` seems liable to make you sad, because it entirely possible that the `>|` will truncate the file before `cat` reads it.

Comment: @larsks what is the idiomatic alternative?

Comment: You would typically use a temporary file that gets cleaned up automatically after the script exits: `tmpfile=$(mktemp rebaseXXXXXX); trap "rm -f $tmpfile" EXIT`; then later on `sed ... $1 > $tmpfile; mv $tmpfile $1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could emulate rebase interactive with a series of cherry-picks and amended commits:

```
git checkout AAAAAA
git cherry-pick BBBBBB -n && git commit --amend -m "AAAAA squashed with BBBBB"
git cherry-pick A3B2C1
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler alternative, if you want to just fix an existing commit from the staging area: (Thanks to @Andrew C for pointing me towards `--fixup`)

```
function git_fix {
    git commit --fixup=$1
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase -i --autosquash "$1^" #empty script
}
```

As a git alias:

```
fix="!f() {\
    git commit --fixup=$1;\
    GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=: git rebase -i --autosquash "$1^";\
}; f"
```