# Squash a merged branch

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I would like to know how squash all commits of merged branch like this :

`feature |    c3 - merge_master - c6
             /     /                \
master  | c1 - c2 - c5 ------------- merge_feature - c7`

and I aim to have this

`master  | c1 - c2 - c5 - squash_c3_c6 - c7`

I found that `git rebase c6 c5 --onto c6` allow me to replay `c3` and `c6` to have `c3'` and `c6'` but I always have `c3` and `c6` in my history.

I must do this in script to process a large repository (over 6k branches !) so I can't use `git rebase -i`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't (quite) get what you want, but what you do get may well be fine.

In Git, "squash" means "copy".  More specifically, a "squash merge" uses Git's merge machinery, performing the *merging action* (the word *merge* as a verb), but then makes an ordinary commit.  Suppose, for instance, you had this:

```
   C3--C6   <-- feature
  /
C1
  \
   C2--C5   <-- master
```

(note that a branch name like `master` or `feature` actually points only to *one* commit, namely the tip commit of the branch; and some commits are on *both* branches, such as `C1`).  Running `git checkout master && git merge --squash feature` would then:

- choose `C1` as the last place the branches shared a commit;
- choose `C5` as the tip of the current branch `master`;
- choose `C6` as the tip of `feature`.

These are the inputs to the merging process ("merge" as a verb).  Then Git will:

- compare `C1` vs `C5`: this is "what we changed";
- compare `C1` vs `C6`: this is "what they changed".

Git then attempts to combine both sets of changes.  If all goes well, the result is placed in the index and the work-tree (is "staged for commit").  Since you used `--squash` which automatically turns on `--no-commit`, Git stops at this point, without making a commit, but does build a pre-loaded commit message.

You can now run `git commit`, which makes an *ordinary* commit (not a merge commit—this uses the word *merge* as an adjective, describing a type of commit).  That ordinary commit would be just what you want:

```
   C3--C6   <-- feature
  /
C1
  \
   C2--C5--C7_which_is_3_plus_6   <-- master (HEAD)
```

At this point the only sensible thing to do with the branch name `feature` is delete it, abandoning original commits `C3` and `C6` (they will eventually, or perhaps even very soon, be garbage-collected: deleting the branch also delete's the branch's reflogs that protect them).

The log message for `C7` is anything you want it to be, but depending on how you configure Git you can get it to default to combining existing log messages from `C3` and `C6` (set `merge.log` to `true` or a number that is at least 2, or use `--log`).

Note that the new commit `C7` that takes what was done in original `C3` and `C6` (minus anything already duplicated by `C5`).  This is what, presumably, makes it safe to delete `feature` entirely like this.

Unfortunately, that's not what you have.  You already have a merge commit reachable from the tip of `feature`, giving the graph that you drew:

```
   C3--C4--C6   <-- feature
  /   /
C1--C2--C5   <-- master
```

The merge base of `feature` and `master` is now, not commit `C1`, but rather commit `C2`.  This is because when we start from `master` and work backwards, we find commits `C5`, then `C2`, then `C1`; and when we start from `feature` and work backwards, we find `C6`, then `C4`, then both `C3` and `C2` simultaneously; and then `C1`.

This means that `C2`, not `C1`, is the "nearest" commit to both branch tips that is on both branches.  Using `git merge --squash` when on `master` will then:

- diff `C2` vs `C5`: what we changed;
- diff `C2` vs `C6`: what they changed;
- combine the changes, and stop due to the implied `--no-commit`

You can then make a new commit `C7`:

```
   C3--C4--C6   <-- feature
  /   /
C1--C2--C5----C7   <-- master
```

Again, the only sensible thing to do with `feature` is to delete it.  The result will be the sequence `...--C1--C2--C5--C7`.  *This is the same sequence of commits as before*, and more importantly, the *tree* (source contents) associated with `C7` should be the same as the tree you'd get without `C4`, as long as `C4` itself is not an [*evil merge*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/1256452) and `C6` does not undo part of `C4`.

The reason for this is that `C4` includes the changes from `C3`, and obviously `C6` includes the changes from `C6`.  This means that when Git ran `git diff C2 C6` it saw the changes in both `C3` and `C6`: those are part of one of the two inputs to the merge-as-a-verb process.  Hence the new `C7` contains all the changes you want.

What it *doesn't* have, depending on `--log` and `merge.log` settings, is *automatic population of the log message*.  But you can edit the log message for `C7` any way you like, including finding an earlier commit like `C1` and using `git log --pretty=short --no-merges <hash>..feature`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `git filter-brabch` which would remove the second parents from the merge commits.

Something like (not tested!)

```
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'read pkey pvalue rest && echo "$pkey $pvalue"' branch_first_commit..branch
```

(it might be faster with sed or awk but I'm afraid to make some mistake with quoting. It may also fail on the first commit)

Explanation: That older history could have conflicts, so replaying the branches history cannot be reliably done automatically. But the "squashed merge" is just the merge with removed second parents. And you already have the merges, so you only need to remove the parents.

Answer (score 0):

So I played with `git filter-branch --parent-filter` its allow me to have all merged branch commits flatten on my master, useful but it loose right ordering of commits => `C1--C3--C2--C4--C5`. The result is good but history become inconsistent, I was expecting something like `C1--C2--C3--C4--C5` and even with this it remain to squash C3 and C4.

@torek thanks for explanations, I better understand that C2 and C3 are equally ancestor of C4 without notion of origin like "commit from feature branch" or "commit from merge branch". And there is "merge commit" but just commit which do a merge.

I found that there is a way to script the [rebase interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner) and like I can achieve what I want with rebase interactive I'm going to script this.

I'll will keep you informed