# Programmatically fixup last commit into previous

Tags: git, rebase, fixup

Every time I want to fixup my latest commit into the second latest commit, I do this

```
git rebase HEAD~2 -i
<replace pick with fixup on line 2>
```

Is there a way to do this in an automated script, without human interference?

I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
git commit --fixup=HEAD
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner)

Comment: @phd Not really, this is a different question that can be solved in many different ways.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

or

```
git reset HEAD~2 --soft
git commit -C ORIG_HEAD^ --reset-author
```

or

```
head=`git log -1 --pretty=%H HEAD~1`
git reset HEAD~2 --hard
git merge --squash ORIG_HEAD
git commit -C $head --reset-author
```

or

```
head=`git log -1 --pretty=%h HEAD~1`
git reset HEAD~2 --hard
git cherry-pick -n HEAD..ORIG_HEAD
git commit -C $head --reset-author
```

The first is enough in your case. The other three are just for fun here, which might be useful in other cases.

**Update**: the explanation of the second:

Suppose we have `A-B-C` as the latest three commits and `C` is the head. What you want is to squash `B` and `C` into a single commit which reuses `B`'s commit message.

`git reset HEAD~2 --soft` resets `HEAD` to `A` and keeps the changes of `B` and `C` in the index and in the working tree. Then a following `git commit` creates a commit that includes the changes in the index, aka the changes of `B` and `C`.

As its name implies, `ORIG_HEAD` points to the original head, in this case the one before last reset, which is `C`. And `ORIG_HEAD^` means the first parent of `ORIG_HEAD`, which is `B`. `-C ORIG_HEAD^` means to reuse the commit message of `B` without edit.

More about [--soft](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset-emgitresetemltmodegtltcommitgt), [-C](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--Cltcommitgt) and [--reset-author](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---reset-author).

Comment: Can you explain the second one a bit? It looks useful but I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @iBug Glad it helps.

Answer (score 5):

> Every time I want to fixup my **latest** commit,

This can be done directly:

```
git commit --amend
```

For **older** commits:

```
git commit --fixup $commit
git rebase HEAD~n -i --autosquash
```

This will automatically interpret the `fixup!` prefixes generated earlier by --fixup (or manually).

Comment: I think I wrote the question wrong. I want to fixup (squash but discard commit message) the latest commit into the previous one.

Comment: Don't make the commit in the first place, `--amend` the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm still looking for a "canonical" solution with Git itself.

Here's my temporary <s>solution</s> workaround:

```
EDITOR="sed -i "2s/pick/fixup/'" git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Basically just replaced an interactive text editor with `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me, full automatic and does does not require any specific sha or anything:

```
git commit -a --fixup HEAD ; GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=touch git rebase --interactive --autosquash HEAD~2
```