# How do I find all commits with a certain message and squash them into the previous commit?

Tags: git, version-control, git-squash, git-amend

When I've been coding I often use `git commit -am <message>` to save my work, and occasionally I'll use `git commit --amend` if I made a mistake in the previous commit. Recently I thought I was being clever and started combining them doing `git commit -am --amend`. Today I looked at my git log and I'm greeted with random tiny commits with the message `--amend`. I understand my mistake now: `--amend` is being interpreted as the message.

Fortunately it doesn't look like there's multiple of these stacked together, so all I need to do is something like `for each commit with '--amend', squash into previous commit`.

Is there a way I can do this?

As an example from my git log:

```
* commit f9d69146e47823d6cdc5e0856257b5f63518268d
| Author: Batman <brucewayne@gmail.com>
| Date:   Mon Aug 5 19:18:21 2019 -0400
| 
|     --amend
| 
* commit b07d42e8802dddc144a795471f789b7eb1475ccb
| Author: Batman <brucewayne@gmail.com>
| Date:   Mon Aug 5 19:07:47 2019 -0400
| 
|     Some key feature that allows user to use product
|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might use `sed` or `awk` for this to manipulate the "rebase script file". We basically reuse this answer:

[How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner)

The manipulation script should look something like this (ATTENTION! untested):

```
#!/usr/bin
sed -i  's/pick \(.*\) --amend/squash \1 --amend/g' $1
```