# git rebase with instructions from a file instead of `--interactive`

Tags: git

I know that `git rebase --interactive` lets me specify which commits to drop, pick, squash, etc. by presenting me with a text editor in which I modify a list of commands.

I'd like to automate a rebase operation by specifying such a list of commands. Is there a way that I can put these commands into a file and have `git rebase` use that file instead of requiring me to manually interact with the text editor?

Comment: You can probably change [GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sequenceeditor) to use a program instead. What interactive rebase do you need to repeat often enough that it could be automated?

Comment: What are you _really_ wishing to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12395024/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+non-interactive+rebase