# How to change all commit messages that contain specific char?

Tags: git

I started a project where I had both FE and BE in the same directory. As project grew larger, it seemed logical to separate them in their own repo.
But the thing that I did is, when I did a commit in FE directory, I prepend commit message with "W:" (e.g. of one commit: "W: Add css style").

Now, when the FE is it's own repo, almost all commit messages have "W:" at the start of the message.

Is there a way to change commits that only have "W:" at the beggining (around 90% of them) and remove these two chars? There are a lot of commits (around 200), and I would not like to reword each individually.

I tried to rebase -i, but hand picking all messages that contain "W:" is time consuming.

Comment: Search for `git filter-repo`. I am pretty sure that it offers a way to automate the change of commit messages.

Comment: Or non-interactive (scripted) `rebase -i`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner

Comment: thanks @j6t, I used `git filter-repo`, specifically this command:

`git filter-repo --message-callback '
return re.sub(b"W: ", b"", message, flags=re.MULTILINE)
' --force`

It worked like a charm