# How can I "splice" two (or more) completely unrelated linear branch ancestries into a new one?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'm trying to combine two branches each with different root commit into a new, empty branch. This is not the usual merge thing as i don't want to have the branches combined only in the last commit (in that case, the new branch would have a merge commit and 'below' still two seperate histories. The new branch would still have two root commits.).

One important fact in my scenario is that both branches are completely unrelated. None commit of either branch affects pathes of the other branches' commits => There will be no conflicts.

Let's assume the following branches:

```
A---B-----C-D
  X---Y-Z
```

This is what i am looking for:

```
A-X-B-Y-Z-C-D
```

The main point is that i want to have the commits in chronological order. 
How to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Really flatten a git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270357/really-flatten-a-git-merge)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You write:

> One important fact in my scenario is that both branches are completely unrelated. No commit of either branch affects patches of the other branches' commits => There will be no conflicts.

Of course, the "splicing" operation you suggest is probably a bad idea if you anticipate that many conflicts will arise. Let's assume that, indeed, nothing bad will happen.

If, at the beginning, your repo looks like this

```
A---B------C--D [branch1]

  X---Y--Z [branch2]
```

you can follow the procedure outlined below to automatically "splice" commits from both branches into a single branch, while maintaining chronological order.

### "Splicing" two unrelated branches

1. Make sure you're in a clean working state; then check out `branch1` and merge `branch2` into it:

   ```
   git checkout branch1
   git merge branch2
   ```

   That will yield

   ```
   A---B------C--D---E [HEAD=branch1]
                    /
     X---Y--Z------- [branch2]
   ```

   Now, I know that's not what you want, but bear with me for a second. We will use merge commit `E` to have access to "the ancestry on both sides" at once.
2. Check out `branch2` and reset it to commit `A`.

   ```
   git checkout branch2
   git reset --hard A
   ```

   You'll be in the following situation:

   ```
   A [HEAD=branch2]
    \
     ---B------C--D---E [branch1]
                     /
      X---Y--Z-------
   ```
3. Generate a list (in chronological order) of all the non-merge commits reachable from `branch1` but not from `branch2`:

   ```
   git rev-list --no-merges --reverse branch2..branch1
   ```

   This should yield the following list of commits: `X`, `B`, `Y`, `Z`, `C`, `D`; commit `E`, which was created in Step 1 will not be in that list, because we used the `--no-merges` flag.
4. Cherry-pick those commits on top of `branch2` (A).

   ```
   git cherry-pick `git rev-list --no-merges --reverse branch2..branch1`
   ```

   Your repo will then look as follows:

   ```
   A--X'--B'--Y'--Z'--C'--D' [HEAD=branch2]
    \
     ---B-----C-D---E [branch1]
                   /
      X---Y-Z------
   ```
5. Delete `branch1`:

   ```
   git branch -D branch1
   ```

   **Edit**: As you correctly remarked, because `branch1` is not fully merged into the current branch (`branch2`), using just `-d` won't do, here; you need to use the `-D` flag instead.

   Your repo will then simply be

   ```
   A--X'--B'--Y'--Z'--C'--D' [HEAD=branch2]
   ```
6. (Optionally) Rename `branch2`:

   ```
   git branch -m branch2 <more_meaningful_name>
   ```

### Generalization to more than two branches

Let's assume you have n completely unrelated branches: `branch1`, `branch2`, ..., `branchn`, where `branch1` corresponds to the branch whose root commit is the oldest commit in the entire repository; Let's call that commit `A`.

```
A ----- o ---- o [branch1]

   o ----- o ---- o -- o [branch2]

...

 o ----- o - o [branchn]
```

If you don't know which commit is `A`, you can identify it by running

```
git rev-list --reverse --max-parents=0 --all
```

The commit ID of `A` will be the first listed in the output of that command. And you can identify which branch is `branch1` by running:

```
git branch -r --contains `git rev-list --reverse --max-parents=0 --all | head -1`
```

Then the procedure outlines in the two-branch case becomes:

1. Create a commit that has access to the ancestry of all branches, by merging all branches other than `branch1` into `branch1`.
2. (same as in two-branch case)
3. (same as in two-branch case)
4. (same as in two-branch case)
5. Delete all branches other than `branch2`.
6. (same as in two-branch case)

Comment: Wow, i am very impressed. I allready verified your procedure with two branches and in worked perfekt. The branch deletion (step 5) has to be done with "-D" as git complains about "not fully merged".
One question to the generalization: What about step 3/4? Do i have to repeat them for each source branch?

Thank you so much!

Comment: There is a less simpler approach (so I think)

1. Rebase Branch2 over Branch 1

2. Run rebase -i, rearrange the commits and continue!

Thoughts?

Comment: @MudassirRazvi I don't think interactive rebase can be used here, because it would be too tedious: the OP has thousands of commits, and rebasing them interactively would force you to consider each of them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Quick simple solution to merge is,

suppose A---B-----C-D (is branch 1) and X---Y-Z (is branch 2).
Take all the patches from branch-2 (git format-patch -n) then apply all the patches on top of branch 1 (git am *.patch), and then shuffle where ever you want the sequence to be using  git rebase -i HEAD~n

Hope that helps!

Comment: "shuffling" seems to be a huge task as my repro has thousands of commits. Is there a way to automate the shuffle? sort by date?