# Apply branch locally only on Git

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I cloned a repository. My local files are "clean", I will call it "**Version A**".

But now I need perform some config changes (connection strings, etc). That changes never need back to server. So I thought about create a new branch with my config changes ONLY. I will call it "**Version B**".

Finally, I will do some local work, bug fixes, etc. I will call it "**Version C**".

Now, I want send my changes to server. My idea is send to server "**Version A**" + "**Version C**", removing added the changes (or ignoring?) on "**Version B**".

I wonder if this is possible, and how I do it?

**EDIT**:
If possible, tell me a ELI5 step by step...

Comment: Did you create separate branches for B and C?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes and No... I dont know what the best pratice here! This is my question!

Comment: You need to reorder the commits `A-B-C` -> `A-C-B`, then push `C`. If you don't know how to do that, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981061/how-to-re-order-commits-in-git-non-interactively or https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to remove the **Version B** in your history.

After `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, your EDITOR will open.  Just remove the FIRST LINE of the content, then save & exit EDITOR.  Then your **Version B** will be removed.